# FileNotFoundError when trying to OCR with pytesseract

Tags: python, popen

Even after looking at the code of subprocess.py, I can't figure out what it is trying to find.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jopa0_000\OneDrive\Koodaus\Python\Map the hex\OCR.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(file)))
  File "C:\Users\jopa0_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 122, in image_to_string
    config=config)
  File "C:\Users\jopa0_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 46, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\jopa0_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\jopa0_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Määritettyä tiedostoa ei löydy
```

Code:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import os


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

image_filenames = os.listdir('screens')

file = "C:\\Users\jopa0_000\OneDrive\Koodaus\Python\Map the hex\screens\\" + image_filenames[0]
print(file)

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(file)))
```

Comment: It is not able to find the tesseract.exe, I think. Add double backslashes in the path to tesseract.exe. Ref: https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract#usage

Comment: `"\t"` is a tab, you need to escape it

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that the format affected the result.